# Run Jquery Slide Toggle on while elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem in running jquery . Here the table sample:

```
table database
id  | name  | value
1     data1   10
2     data2   20
3     data3   30
4     data4   40
5     data5   50
```

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM database ORDER BY id"
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    while($row  = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {?>
        <div id="flip">
            <?php echo $row['name']?>
        </div>

        <div id="panel">
            <?php echo $row['value']?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

But the slide toogle jquery only execute once, on the first element.  How to make slide toggle execute every row in while looping?
Here is my slidetoggle()Jquery:

```
    <script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

And the CSS :

```
<style> 
#panel, #flip {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e5eecc;
    border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

#panel {
    padding: 50px;
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Jack A. answer, build first your HTML with classes instead of multiples IDs. Then, in your script, use `jQuery.next()` to find the next panel element and toggle it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flip").click(function(){
        $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qmnaffkg/) illustrating this.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same id in multiple elements. Build a unique id for every element. E.g. flip1, flip2, etc. and panel1, panel2, etc.

Comment: yah, what should i do with the script then?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating multiple HTML elements with the same ID ("flip" and "panel"), which is not correct; IDs should be unique.

An alternative is to use a class instead of an ID:

```
while($row  = $result->fetch_assoc())
{?>
    <div class="flip">
        <?php echo $row['name']?>
    </div>

    <div class="panel">
        <?php echo $row['value']?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flip").click(function(){
        $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

This will act on all of the elements simultaneously.

Comment: how to make it not simultaneously?

Comment: @RYANTO Then you will need to use unique IDs and specify which one you want to show/hide. You haven't given us any information about how you want to select which element is toggled, so no way to tell you how to write the script.

Comment: The result will be show 5 "flip" and all of these will have a toggled function, so if i click 1 "flip" that flip will show it's panel. So all flip i want to toggled